Problems about Using Agda in VSCode
I am trying to use Agda in VSCode. I think I have downloaded all the required extensions, and I still obtain the following error messages:
dyld[9071]: Library not loaded: @loader_path/dylib/libicuuc.73.dylib
Referenced from: <41CE9F56-E2D2-3C41-8137-4FCDB6FDAE40> /Users/mac/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/banacorn.agda-mode/v0.2.6.4.0.3-darwin/als
Reason: tried: '/Users/mac/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/banacorn.agda-mode/v0.2.6.4.0.3-darwin/dylib/libicuuc.73.dylib' (not a mach-o file), '/usr/local/lib/libicuuc.73.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicuuc.73.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
[Error - 3:38:36 AM] Server initialization failed.
Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
Code: -32097
[Error - 3:38:36 AM] Agda Language Server client: couldn't create connection to server.
Message: Pending response rejected since connection got disposed
Code: -32097
Following ChatGPT's advice, I searched for solutions related to libicuuc.73.dylib and attempted the commands suggested in this Stack Overflow thread: dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.62.dylib error running php after installing node with brew on Mac. Unfortunately, I continue to receive error messages despite multiple attempts.
P.S. I am not familiar with the commands in terminal and how it works. Any help would be appreciated.

Disable the "Agda Language Server" in the settings.

@NaïmFavier This indeed works!
